# What alphabet is this?

Tags: word, language, cipher

You find yourself trapped on a strange planet, whose residents use an English alphabet made of English symbols. You are given a piece of paper with the following sentences in it.

```
./4)-5/ t- -+2 8-5/
9| y-+ =2/ 8/2/ t- )-61+/2 +3 t+26 8-5/ 6-.
t893 3-)9/ty 93 89784y =,0=6)/,
t8/ t=(4/ -| /4/5/6t3 )-6t=963 =)t969+5
```

What does the message say, and where does the planet's alphabet come from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that the answer is:

> the alphabet belongs to the Texas instruments graphing calculator TI-89

Khale_Kitha has decoded the message as

> welcome to our home
>  if you are here to conquer us turn home now
>  this society is highly advanced
>  the table of elements contains actinium

The atomic number of actinium is 89, and all letters in the encoded message are from keys on the Texas instruments graphing calculator TI-89.

Answer (score 5):

I think the answer is:

> Uranus

I looked for commonalities between the words to get a substitute started.  It looks like:

> `t` and `y` mean themselves.  They have not been changed.

This gives a starting point.

> The letter o is a common letter and I see it at the beginning of the phrase.  Used in `to`.  This also helps with `u`, giving the words `our` and `you`.

Judging by the number of letters, in the first sentence, I've deemed it to state:

> Welcome to our home

Working, from this assumption, I have a partial cypher.

> welcome to our home
>  9| you =re here to co61uer u3 tur6 home 6ow
>  th93 3oc9ety 93 h97hly =,0=6ce,
>  the t=(le o| eleme6t3 co6t=963 =ct969um

Now, I know a few more letters.  I can assume:

> `=` is `a`.  And the third sentence says: "This society is highly advanced"

This gives me more to work with.

I run it again.

> welcome to our home
>  i| you are here to con1uer us turn home now
>  this society is highly advanced
>   the ta(le o| elements contains actinium

Clearly, we're near the end.  Add the last few letters and:

> welcome to our home
>  if you are here to conquer us turn home now
>  this society is highly advanced
>  the table of elements contains actinium

Now....

> Where can we find actinium?

This is where it gets a little shaky, and I'm not certain.

> if you are here to conquer us turn home now
>  this society is highly advanced
>
>  A society with nuclear bombs could be considered highly advanced.
>  actinium is found as a byproduct of uranium.  The catch, though, is that I'm basing the answer purely off the relationship between the words Uranium, and Uranus.

I used the following to decrypt, making it as I went:

> ```
> void Main()
>  {
>    string phrase = @"./4)-5/ t- -+2 8-5/
>    9| y-+ =2/ 8/2/ t- )-61+/2 +3 t+26 8-5/ 6-.
>    t893 3-)9/ty 93 89784y =,0=6)/,
>    t8/ t=(4/ -| /4/5/6t3 )-6t=963 =)t969+5";
>
>
>    Dictionary Cypher = new Dictionary()
>    {
>      { '.', 'w' },
>      { '/', 'e' },
>      { '4', 'l' },
>      { ')', 'c' },
>      { '-', 'o' },
>      { '5', 'm' },
>      { 't', 't' },
>      { '+', 'u' },
>      { '2', 'r' },
>      { '8', 'h' },
>      { 'y', 'y' },
>      { '=' , 'a' },
>      { '9' , 'i' },
>      { '3' , 's' },
>      { '7' , 'g' },
>      { ',' , 'd' },
>      { '6' , 'n' },
>      { '0' , 'v' },
>      { '|' , 'f' },
>      { '(' , 'b' },
>      { '1' , 'q' },
>    }; 
>
>
>    GetDecoded(phrase, Cypher).Dump();
>  }
>  
>  public string GetDecoded(string phrase, Dictionary cypher)
>  {
>    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
>    for (int i = 0; i < phrase.Length; i++)
>    {
>      try
>      {
>        result.Append(cypher.Single(a => a.Key == phrase[i]).Value);
>      }
>      catch
>      {
>        result.Append(phrase[i]);
>      }
>    }
>    return result.ToString();
>  }
> ```

Comment: You are right in terms of what the message says, but not on how the key was generated. What other properties does actinium have?

Comment: There's a lot of them, unless you're referring to their suspected usage in the destruction of the Star Wars Universe planet, Caamas, in which case, there wasn't a specific planet that did that.  Hah

Comment: Well, more specifically, there's a specific number that helps.

Comment: You got me, then, I think.  The best I was coming up with was two planets which could be a specific distance away from us, but those distances change, regularly, and so couldn't be accurate.  There were two stars whose information matched some details about actinium, but those aren't planets.  I look forward to seeing the answer, but I feel like more information is needed, or I'm missing something important.

Comment: You're being thrown off by the idea that it has something to do with planets; it doesn't.

Comment: Yah, when I was digging into this one i came up with the same decoded message and ended up looking at stars.  Theres a few things that stand out, but i think we need a small push in the right direction @Eridan

Comment: the answer youre looking for it isnt a rot13(*NYCUN* org fhofgvghgvba pvcure) is it? cuz a major property of actinium is rot13(nycun rzvffvbaf)

Comment: I think it's a calculator. The poster asked us to find where the alphabet came from, basically where did they find this set of symbols for a representation of language. The numbers 0-9, and symbols +, -, =, (, ), ., x, y, and t, are on my calculator. Not sure what use the | symbol is.

Comment: @Khale_Kitha: The  atomic number of actinium is 89. This hints at the Texas instruments graphing calculator TI-89, from which the alphabet is taken.

Comment: A bit weak.  I can think of a number of things that use this "alphabet", related to the number 89, from a certain typewriter to mini-keyboards with exactly 89 keys.  It does match, but I just think it's a bit vague.